# Counting iterations in three nested loops

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Here is the code:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  for (j = 1; j <= n; j += i) {
    for (k = 1; k <= n; k++) {
      // basic_step
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my attempt :
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{\frac{n}{i}}\sum_{k=1}^{n}1= \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n^2}{i}= n^2 \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}$$

And from here I assumed that $k=\log(i)$ which means $2^k=i$.
And the sum will look like that
$$n^2 \sum_{k=0}^{\log(n)}\frac{1}{2^k}$$
which is for sure greater than $n^2$
And if we tend the sum to infinty and not just $\log(n)$ we get $$n^2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty }\frac{1}{2^k} \le 2n^2$$
And now it's obviously  $T(n) \in \theta(n^2)$
For some reason it's wrong and I'm here to ask what I did wrong.

Please note: I'm looking for the $\Theta$  notation and the Big-O and if your answer will include any integrals please just don't do it I'm not allowed to do it with integrals.

Comment: What is the question? This looks like an order $n^3$ loop to me.

Comment: @JohnDouma Yes, got it. There are three nested loops, and he wants to find the total number of iterations. But then it's relatively easy, $n^2\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1i=n^2H_n\sim n^2\log(n)$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut But why this is true there should be a away to get that the hirmonic sum is indeed log(n) in this question

Comment: You can easily prove that $H_{2n}-H_{n}>\frac{1}{2}$, then $H_{2^n}>n$.

Comment: Thanks for your response I'm satisfied enough